# Idiom, analogous to Russian "to soap the rope" -- as intention to (figuratively) "kill somebody"

Tags: idiom-requests

There is an idiom in Russian "to soap the rope". It refers to the action performed prior to hanging someone: if rope is greased with soap, noose knot will slide better.

In the case of *My boss is soaping the rope* it's pretty similar to "My boss is gonna hang me". But there is more to this idiom:

*I'm soaping the rope* -- it may be used by person who anticipates bad things will happen almost inevitably (exam is coming, but person is unprepared). OR If person feels depressed or physically/intellectually suffers (in pain, overwhelmed by work, very tired). All in all, declaration of suicidal thoughts, but without genuine desire to commit suicide.

Or it even may be used in positive context. Say, as "ROFL": *I'm laughing so hard, I'm gonna soap the rope* (I'm gonna die). Or *Can't wait for this party, I'm already soaping the rope* (party will surely be awesome).

Comment: In my family we say things like *Shall I fetch the Stanley [knife]?* if someone's vociferously bewailing their bad situation (alluding to the idea of offering someone an ultra-sharp blade so they can cut their own throat and spare the rest of us having to listen to the constant whingeing). But we're a bit of an oddball family, and I doubt our whimsical turn of phrase would count as an "idiom".

Comment: @FumbleFingers yep, "soap a rope" can be used in this context also, but I need something widespread, so listener/reader will not have to think about the meaning neither twice or even once  =)

Comment: Not quite as far (or self-inflicted) as 'kick the bucket'?

Comment: @marcellothearcane nope, the nuance is that it is a "preparation", per se it's expectation or declaration of something almost inevitable will happen. it's like lacing the boots before you kick the bucket ((% and it may be applied to 3rd person. are constructions like *Boss gonna kick my bucket next monday* even used =))

Comment: @jungle_mole so the sharpening of the axe before the execution... I'm sure there is one, but I can't remember it at the moment!

Comment: Is it one of these: http://masterrussian.com/proverbs/russian_proverbs.htm - https://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Russian_proverbs - https://www.lonweb.org/links/russian/lang/030.htm

Comment: Here are a few comments on the saying: https://everything2.com/title/Soap+on+a+rope

Comment: I guess a weaker variant would be "I'll get my coat" in anticipation of being kicked out after having done/said something.

Comment: I can think of a few that relate to someone being about to die - "measuring him for a coffin" or "picking out flowers for his funeral"; or implying that I'm about to kill someone - "I'll swing for him"; but nothing that says a third party is about to kill me.
Possibly "he's on the warpath" comes closest?

Comment: @RupertMorrish "measuring somebody for a coffin" is the closest. at least at the first glance, it pretty much satisfies everything. the fact that someone can't measure another person in absentia (but can soap the rope) is not significant, since it is used figuratively anyway.

Comment: @Josh pages you've linked contain like 90% of proverbs and 10% of sayings. this idiom is closer to being a saying, but it is neither saying, nor proverb anyway. i've seen a page at everything2.com, it is mostly irrelevant. the last comment addresses this idiom somehow, but fails to elaborate to the fullness and offers no corresponding idiom in english.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not entirely certain, after reading the question, whether the request is for a phrase that indicates suicidal ideation OR homicidal ideation on the part of another; in either case it seems that the intended effect is humorous or flippant rather than serious, so:

Homicidal:
In our house, my better half and I joke that one or the other of us is *buttering the stairs*; I am almost certain that I stole this from P.G. Wodehouse, but I can't find the reference.  The implication, of course, is that one of us is going to try to kill the other by causing an accident; equally of course, it's implicit that both of us know that this is a joke.

Suicidal:
We sometimes refer to sticking one's *head in the oven*, a reference to Sylvia Plath's chosen exit.  This is almost always used in a humorous way, as in this [1978 "Garfield" cartoon](https://garfield.com/comic/1978/10/18), or in Tom Petty's song *Yer So Bad*:

> My sister's ex-husband
>   Can't get no lovin'
>   Walks around dog-faced and hurt
>   Now he's got nothin',
>   Head in the oven
>   I can't decide which is worse...

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two phrases that might fit.

*Dead man walking* -
Which refers to a man on his way to execution. Great phrase, but it is more of a title than something you'd do to the person like your original. This works great with your examples of a looming exam without hope or a person who has a broken spirit.

*Giving last rites* -
That's got a bit of a Catholic overtone to it. But Hollywood has made it a fairly well understood phrase. I would say "Give me my last rites, I'm done", but I can't picture my boss being involved.

Answer (score 0):

We have something similar, but the gist of it is confirmation, rather than preparation.

> Stick me with a fork, I'm done.

It's a productive meme, it can be used in first, second and third person, and it can refer to just about any sense of *done*, including *done for*.

And there's the ever popular harbinger of doom

> I think I hear banjos.

This is a reference to the movie *Deliverance*, which doesn't end well for the tourists.

Answer (score -1):

Just the 2 words "Cement shoes" implies death by drowning.  Used more in the context of death by another rather than by one's own hand: "They gave him a pair of cement shoes".  A popular film & book portrayal in the 20th century of the way mobsters killed someone was to set a person's feet into wet cement, and when the cement was dry, drop them into the bay.  If someone inquired as to the whereabouts of the victim it was then said "He swims with the fishes". 
  To indicate suicidal thoughts a person would say, "I'm going to swim with the fishes" rather than, "I'm going to get me a pair of cement shoes."